# Why sqlservr.exe process is consuming CPU because of temp.db?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, temp-tables, ssms

I was looking at the statistics of sqlservr.exe and it is consuming a lot of cpu time in some "aleatory" moments, like 6am. There is no job consuming it. But I saw that temp.db is doing some create and delete object.

Is this some internal process or there is something wrong in my database that is doing it?

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768(v=sql.100).aspx) is a list of things MSSQL uses TempDB for. You will notice that it is used to store intermediate results from other jobs/SP's as well. If you have other jobs scheduled around the time you see the spike in TempDB usage, that is probably why.

Comment: @GVashist, Is there any way to see something like a log about what tempdb is doing?

Comment: From the same article: "Operations within tempdb are minimally logged." You could get an idea about its usage by using filters on the SQL profiler but I doubt you will see the actual queries that are using the database at that time.